# How to select specific columns in typeorm querybuilder

Tags: sql, typescript, typeorm

I tried to select specific columns by joining tables in typeorm.

When I see following materials there is sample code.

https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/select-query-builder#joining-relations

```
const user = await createQueryBuilder("user")
    .leftJoinAndSelect("user.photos", "photo")
    .where("user.name = :name", { name: "Timber" })
    .getOne();
```

```
import {Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, OneToMany} from "typeorm";
import {Photo} from "./Photo";

@Entity()
export class User {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    name: string;

    @OneToMany(type => Photo, photo => photo.user)
    photos: Photo[];
}
```

```
import {Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, ManyToOne} from "typeorm";
import {User} from "./User";

@Entity()
export class Photo {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    url: string;

    @ManyToOne(type => User, user => user.photos)
    user: User;
}
```

for example my desired result is following.`where user.name =="Timber"`

```
{
id: user.id
name: user.name
url: photo.url
}
```

Are there any good way to achieve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
const user = await createQueryBuilder("user")
    .leftJoinAndSelect("user.photos", "photo")
    .select(['user.id', 'user.name', 'photo.url']) // added selection
    .where("user.name = :name", { name: "Timber" })
    .getOne();
```

By this query, you'll get:

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: 'Timber',
  photos: [{ url: 'someurl1' }, ..., { url: 'someurlN' }]
}
```

Comment: How to assign alias for those selected columns? I tried `.select(['user.id', 'user.name', 'photo.url'],['userId','username','url'])`, but this approach did not work

Comment: @AkhilMohandas try `.select(['user.id AS userId', 'user.name AS username', 'photo.url AS url'])`

Comment: @ArtOlshansky I have tried `'delivery.delivery_type AS type'` with `getOne`. unable to get alias. its working with getRawOne().but I need getOne().

https://stackoverflow.com/q/72901411/4909563

Comment: Make sure to not put the aliases in quotation marks. E.g. this doesn't work:  .select(["user"."id", "user"."name"]). Doing this only works with getRawOne(). For the mapping to work, the aliases must not be in quotes.

Answer (score 8):

When you want to select particular columns you have to use getRawOne like below,

```
const user = await createQueryBuilder("user")
    .leftJoinAndSelect("user.photos", "photo")
    .select(['user.id', 'user.name', 'photo.url']) 
    .where("user.name = :name", { name: "Timber" })
    .getRawOne();
```

Comment: Just wanna complete this answers: In my experience, it does not matter if you wanna use `getRawMany`, `getRawOne`, or [`execute`](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/1832), or other methods. You need to keep in mind that for some reason you need to chain your `select` at the end of the methods -- `createQueryBuilder("tb").leftJoinAndSelect("tb.tb2", "tb2").otherMethods().select([/* fields */]).getOne();`