# How to select specific columns in TypeORM query builder (many to many relation)

Tags: sql, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

I've been searching for information and solutions and couldn't find anything that matches my problem.
The most closer one was this question [ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64401212/how-to-select-specific-columns-in-typeorm-querybuilder?newreg=88f0c8cadd924456a61eddb8a5611421 ] and I used it like an starting point.

I use PostgreSQL and my ENTITIES are:

**User Entity:**

```
@Entity('user')
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @CreateDateColumn({
    type: 'timestamp',
    default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)',
  })
  createdAt: Date;

  @CreateDateColumn({
    type: 'timestamp',
    default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)',
    onUpdate: 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)',
  })
  updatedAt: Date;

  @ApiProperty()
  @Column({ type: 'varchar', default: null })
  name: string;

  ..... more columns .......

  @ManyToMany(() => Calendar)
  @JoinTable({
    name: 'users_calendars',
    joinColumn: {
      name: 'idUser',
      referencedColumnName: 'id',
    },
    inverseJoinColumn: {
      name: 'idCalendar',
      referencedColumnName: 'idCalendar',
    },
  })
  calendars: Calendar[];
}
```

**Calendar Entity:**

```
@Entity('calendar')
export class Calendar {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  idCalendar: number;

  @CreateDateColumn({
    type: 'timestamp',
    default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)',
  })
  createdAt: Date;

  @CreateDateColumn({
    type: 'timestamp',
    default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)',
    onUpdate: 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)',
  })
  updatedAt: Date;

  @Column('varchar')
  operation: string;

  @Column('varchar', { nullable: true })
  url?: string;

  @Column('varchar', { nullable: true })
  path?: string;
}
```

So, with this in mind I want to create a query that gets all the related calendars to a certain user.

I've been trying some raw SQL queries and what I want is something like this:

```
SELECT 
    "calendar"."idCalendar",  
    "calendar"."operation",  
    "calendar"."url",  
    "calendar"."path" 
FROM 
    "user" "user" 
LEFT JOIN 
    "users_calendars" "user_calendar" ON "user_calendar"."idUser"="user"."id"
LEFT JOIN 
    "calendar" "calendar" ON "calendar"."idCalendar"="user_calendar"."idCalendar" 
WHERE 
    "user"."id" = 1 and (
        "calendar"."operation" like '%1636454981858%' or 
        "calendar"."operation" like '%IVA%' or
        "calendar"."operation" like '%condition 3%'
    )
```

This query works!!

What I'm doing with nestjs and typeorm is using this queryBuilder method like this:

```
let queryCalendars = `"calendar"."operation" like '%IVA%' or "calendar"."operation" like '%1636454785616-914385082%' or "calendar"."operation" like '%IVA 3%' or "calendar"."operation" like '%IVA 4%'`;

const user: User = await this.connection
      .getRepository(User)
      .createQueryBuilder('user')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('user.calendars', 'calendar')
      .select([
        'calendar.idCalendar',
        'calendar.operation',
        'calendar.url',
        'calendar.path',
      ])
      .where(`user.id = :idUser and (${queryCalendars})`, { idUser })
      .getOne();
```

And creates this query:

```
SELECT 
    "calendar"."idCalendar" AS "calendar_idCalendar", 
    "calendar"."operation" AS "calendar_operation", 
    "calendar"."url" AS "calendar_url", 
    "calendar"."path" AS "calendar_path" 
FROM 
    "user" "user" 
LEFT JOIN 
    "users_calendars" "user_calendar" ON "user_calendar"."idUser"="user"."id" 
LEFT JOIN 
    "calendar" "calendar" ON "calendar"."idCalendar"="user_calendar"."idCalendar" 
WHERE 
    "user"."id" = :idUser and (
        "calendar"."operation" like '%IVA%' or 
        "calendar"."operation" like '%1636454785616-914385082%' or 
        "calendar"."operation" like '%IVA 3%' or 
        "calendar"."operation" like '%IVA 4%'
    )
```

This query does NOT work!!!!

I'm losing my mind because I can't find out what's the difference between those queries and why I can get it working...

What I expect to get is something like:

```
[
 { 
   idCalendar: 1, 
   operation: "operation-name", 
   url: "https://some.url", 
   path: "./some/path" 
 },
 ...
]
```

But instead I get *undefined*...

Comment: I think the problem that it doesnt read `idUser`, try : `user.id = ${idUser} ... ` and check if you're propely passed the value, ps : test with a static id first

Comment: @Youba Thanks but I've already try that and it doesn't work... I think the problem might be at the select part so it's the only different part of the queries