# unable to select alias in getMany Typeorm

Tags: mysql, nestjs, typeorm, query-builder, node.js-typeorm

I'm using TypeORM(mySQL) for my Nestjs App. I want to change the column name on select using querybuilder. but it's not working.

```
const order = await this.connection
        .createQueryBuilder(Orders,"order")
        .where("customer_id = :userId", { userId })
        .select(["order.id","order.hashed_id AS hash","order.paid AS payment"])
        .getMany();
```

same applies on **leftjoin** and **addSelect**

```
.leftJoin("variety.product","product")
.addSelect([`product.name_${language} AS name`,"product.image_url"])
```

How Can we set Alia's in TypeORM

Answer (score 0):

I was also struggling with this. Apparently you have to use `getRawMany()` instead of `getMany()` because the return data is not an entity. Found this out here https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/9114

Answer (score -1):

Just remove "[]". addSelect have two overlap:

- addSelect(queryStrs: string[])
- addSelect(queryStr: string, alias: string)

  ```
  .addSelect(`product.name_${language} AS name`,"product.image_url")
  ```

Comment: @Tran that's the wrong syntax. I want to use n columns which is not possible with this.